# what is the the difference between Dataflow model and RTL style coding in verilog/SystemC

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, systemc

I have studied in my school that both the models are used in same perspective but when i went through  online there are pages which define some tips to convert Dataflow models to RTL models, so can someone explain me with an example what is the difference exactly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data flow model

```
module #(parameter width = 8) array_multiplier(    
     input [width-1:0] a, b,
     output [width-1:0] y
);
   assign Y = a * b;
endmodule
```

This is an RTL model of a multiplier (extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16733809/2755607))

```
module #(parameter width = 8) array_multiplier_(    
     input clk,
     input [width-1:0] a, b,
     output [width-1:0] y
);   
reg [width-1:0] a_pipeline [0:width-2];
reg [width-1:0] b_pipeline [0:width-2];
reg [width-1:0] partials [0:width-1];
integer i;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    a_pipeline[0] <= a;
    b_pipeline[0] <= b;
    for (i = 1; i < width-1; i = i+1) begin
        a_pipeline[i] <= a_pipeline[i-1];
        b_pipeline[i] <= b_pipeline[i-1];
    end

    partials[0] <= a[0] ? b : 0;
    for (i = 1; i < width; i = i+1)
        partials[i] <= (a_pipeline[i-1][i] ? b_pipeline[i-1] << i : 0) +
                partials[i-1];
end

assign y = partials[width-1];

endmodule
```

Comment: It seems "data flow" is used interchangeably with "behaviour" for verilog... To me, a verilog module is either RT level or a much higher, human friendly form no matter it's called data flow model or behaviour model.

Comment: @Light there's actually gate-wire modeling also.  A successful design might use a mix of all three.  The main division in my experience is "synthesizable or not?"  Because if not just tinkering there is little use in writing anything other than synthesizable code.  Whether it's gate, RTL, or behavioral.